# WP8: reduce the pivot page header size?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to reduce the header text `item1` in pivot page. But, i dunno how to do. Is there anyway to reduce this font size ?

XAML Code;

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change `HeaderTemplate`. Smth like this:

```
<phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="40" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the font size in PivotItem. Instead you can create a Template where you can add a TextBlock and consider it as a header. Please find the sample here.

```
<controls:Pivot Title="whatever" Name="pivot">
    <controls:PivotItem Margin="11,28,13,0" >
        <controls:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Name="FirstPivot" FontSize="31" Text="FirstPivot" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid>    <!-- content --> </Grid>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: <controls:pivot> is for WP7 and its used in vs 2010. am asking for wp8 vs 2012

Comment: it will be working in wp8 also. Even we are also developing using 2012 only.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone 8 remember to change the 'controls' to 'phone'.

```
<phone:Pivot Title="whatever" Name="pivot">
    <phone:PivotItem Margin="11,28,13,0" >
        <phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Name="FirstPivot" FontSize="31" Text="FirstPivot" />
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid>    <!-- content --> </Grid>
</phone:Pivot>
```